# connect via netcat and send messages in bash script

Tags: networking, bash, scripts, netcat

When I am writing a bash script like the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

nc localhost [pseudoport]
echo "test"
```

it connects to the server but does not send the text "test".

It works with

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "test" | nc localhost [pseudoport]
```

The problem here is that the connection exits after something has been received.

How can I send multiple messages, in my case a fixed preamble followed by a variable data?

Comment: You are running the script in the command line correct?

Comment: yes that is correct

Comment: What do you mean "send continuously"? Do you want to send a fixed preamble followed by variable data from a file or standard input through `nc` (or any process consuming its standard input stream for that matter)?

Comment: Yes @DavidFoerster I wanted to send a fixed preamble followed by a variable data. The link I posted describes how you should do it (from a file).

Comment: @DavidFoerster done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a way to do this here: [Send Commands to socket using netcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21130757/send-commands-to-socket-using-netcat)

You have to put the messages you want to send in a textfile (lets say `msg.txt`) and then

```
nc localhost [pseudoport] < msg.txt
```

The text file should look like this:

```
message1
message2
message3
...
```

Every message has to be in a new line.

The link I posted has a better explanation why this has to be done the way it is done here (there is no explanation in the duplicate article).